# Error with long doubles on PowerPC when compiling with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point, powerpc, long-double

I'm running into a curious bug when I assign values to `long double` variable types. (PowerPC architecture, gcc v4.9.2)

Specifically:

```
const constexpr long double DEGREE_TO_RAD = 0.0174532925199432954743716805978693;
const constexpr long double RAD_TO_DEGREE = 1. / DEGREE_TO_RAD;
```

seems to result in the following compiler error:

```
error: ‘(1.0e+0l / 1.74532925199432954743716805978693e-2l)’ is not a constant expression
 const constexpr long double RAD_TO_DEGREE = 1. / DEGREE_TO_RAD;
```

I am not an expert in C++; this is software I'm attempting to build specifically for my development machine's environment. However, my research has led me to the following tidbit:

> On some PowerPC and SPARCv9 machines, `long double` is implemented as a double-double arithmetic, where a `long double` value is regarded as the exact sum of two double-precision values, giving at least a 106-bit precision; with such a format, the `long double` type does not conform to the IEEE floating-point standard. Otherwise, `long double` is simply a synonym for `double` (double precision). [[wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double#Implementations)

Which leads me to believe the build failure is due to long double having a different interpretation in my architecture vs the standard x86. Changing `long double` to `double` in the source allows the compilation to succeed. Is this a coincidence? Why would g++ throw a fit about it in this instance?

Comment: Not your problem, but I'd compute all constants from a single definition of `pi`, and would reserve **ALL UPPERCASE** for macros. Using that convention for constants is a Java/Python thing. Those languages don't have a preprocessor.

Comment: For some weird reason on godbolt with powerpc compilers `const constexpr long double RAD_TO_DEGREE = pow(DEGREE_TO_RAD, -1.0l);` works... while on x86 the clang will bail out as `pow` being non-const function, and gcc works either way. Unfortunately I don't have any explanation, `1.0l / <long double constant>` seems to me as something what can be definitely computed at compile time, even if with risk of some minor accuracy loss, that would be maybe worth of warning without some explicit way of noting some inaccuracy is fine.

Comment: Why not just remove the `constexpr`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It's quite pointless in modern C++ to reserve all uppercase for macros, because you basically should avoid macros completely. In some unfortunate case you need macros, you can still use something like `MACRO_<SOME_UPPERCASE_NAME>`, so at least anyone reading source will be aware which part of source needs refactoring. ... And by removing `constexpr` you completely change the meaning of the definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791333/constexpr-errors-with-floating-point-representation.

Comment: @Ped7g: Your idea of a common prefix for macros is interesting, but IMO utterly impractical. The note about changing the meaning of the definition is pretty much meaningless, as I see it. There's nothing you can do  at compile time with a compile time floating point constant, other than computing other such constants.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf how about being termination condition in `for` loop? ... tried it on godbolt ... x86-64 gcc 7.3 will just calculate result of some summing loop and return that, power pc gcc generates actual loop. The x86-64 generates result at compile time even without `constexpr` .. thinking about it, I can pretty much agree, that the resulting machine code will be highly likely same in both cases, but the source is semantically different a lot. And powerpc compilers available at godbolt are hopelessly inefficient when compared to modern x86 versions :/

Comment: are you compiling with `-frounding-math` by any chance?

Comment: note that you need the L suffix for `long double` because `0.0174532925199432954743716805978693` and `1.` are `double` constants

Comment: @PeteBecker  & @M.M : I see the same, without specifying `-frounding-math` using a powerpc64le compiler. So, perhaps not a dup.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug (or perhaps multiple bugs) related to `constexpr`.  Clang for PowerPC [does compile your snippet](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxLrwAOqBYXW09hk4IeXmp0Vjb2Rk4uPIrKmKo%2BDATMxAR%2BxqacsSohtEkpBGF2js6uismp6QFZChWF1sWRpTwAlIqoBsTIHADkrHTAANToHQ7sg1QQ/aLDo%2BMAHi3iAAwAguIA7LJrg7uDaLS1%2B3S1mPNuxIPTQyMGY5iDACLYAOIAStjYAPoAKgDyXzeq0eg3EAGYQcsAHTLTgbbgAVjBkgAnJIEZwUSjuMiUQjuPCwRtOAA2AAcywRKI2ZJJKLB4O2qz2x0OBFZp3Ol2uszu4yBj1%2BAOe70%2BoIhg04UMGAHonq8Pt9/oDgYyVsy9sRMAROrRBvMAFQCoVfEWKtVrTaPdXqnm3e4TSRTAa8h2LG1bdUsg5HH0EM4XK4u%2B3jM2fE0C8WQmFwxG49GY7G4/GE4nkynU2n0iwWjW7P0c/1coMzEMPY3KsPYKOSqEWWXy0VKgEC3MsrU64h6w0V4UKz65q3qnptVggHoInqkUw9ZZT1DjnRyOSDBQdLoPKRgzhTgjjuctNoAaxAYJRUJJCOWKM4FJJRMksIRCKE4%2B4U5nc9IC56U4UIGWUg91nEdSDgWAkDQIw3DwdgyAoCAoJguCQDcNxkBJbhkGEURSCoWD/WIf8IAcfcpwcawUgAT3HHdSCgowtAIP5aFYGiQNILAjBEYB2DIzi8C1BIADdMH/DizniAx/VoqdrH9McONYPAHGIai9CwWSgOIPAjFktoaHoJg2A4GIBCyHCxGXGQhBU/9IDaVA3FycSAFo/kkQZXNqdBwUeCQZDkHg/ziBINAgcwqkyUhzCKCIokCTxvDoKLEuCHw4pKaJsniXJ8kqfQMkEJQckSOpMqabLagKVKanKhp4uaNo106bouFHcdJ2nfifw8AB3Zx0Mw/ZLMGCACGIAxaCPFoxtwQgSFBSRt1IQY9Gg2DnCW7dZqXQKZF3Mi2ggSDUA2uDyEoJDNpcNCMO4FRLLwgjnGI0iOIo2hqK0himJYtj%2BK4ni%2BI4/AhLUUTxK/STkGk3o6Pk5R%2BOU1T1IweHdx0vSeh3Ay6EYFg%2BLMkBJCEHiUGs%2BQUfsiBHOcnw3I8ryfL8gLZBkTg6JK3KfE0bRapi7QKoSrIgmS3xCuqUgxdyYXmhysK8jqAXucV/L6nCLLiuVyXouq1I5eiZr1zazgOonD8evHfrnEw8ZsJ4saJqmma5vwIhLi3LI1rO5Ctq3SRdspw6QOO07zucS7EN9m7UKGh74ie/DWEIt7%2BM%2B76canX76H%2B9ivyB0QQYLwSech/iYbhrTEcUr8UbU4gqI0jHtN0/S8Px4yid4AQwTJ0QKf2qm7PgOmXPHbyCF8iE2aC98FdyPndF1swhYarXRaS3IBZljL18q4rQrynX/D1o%2ByoKQ3tZqle6sv/eReN1rTPNrrP3na3UAG4g7YeB2ZnGpNaas0IDzQ9ttb260/ae2WmCIOQ8Q4HmPCAEk0IwTcBRMsMkmIwQkkkBsFEZJESvh6PPPSnBliAXft%2Bccf4AJASOubSQlsOI/kQSONookiK824EAA) without any issues. And if you remove the `constexpr` then GCC also compiles it properly in both [C mode](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtag1egAyeWpgByegEaZiXXgAdU0wktqad%2Bwc9eK6puZWurb2PDJymAruDATMxASeegacEfL%2BtLHxBIGWNnYOMnEJSd6p0sU5ZnkhBTwAlDKo2sTIHADkrHTAANTozdbsPVQQXaJ9A0MAHvUApAAMAIKzAOwAQguLPds9aLQVPWO9/dqDmD0AItgA4gBK2NhiACoA8mK3ixc9swDMX/MAOnmnBW3AArD8AEwATkhYM40Oh3Ch0LB3FBPxWnAAbAAOeZg6ErXHY6E/X4bJY7XZ0A5HCanIYfC7PN5XO4Pb5/HqcAE9AD0lxu90er3enwpm2pxEwBBatB6UwAVMzWWJ2SLJUtVhdNpt6SczsNIaNugyjTM9espTs9nSzYahhqHmrmVz/kCQeCUXCEUiUWiMVi8QSiSSycYtVtbbSCIcHZNzqqxc7sO6eQDjAKhRzRW9mVHpbL5YqVZ81amozrNu1GqwQO0we1SAZ2vNm6gG%2BoetJmq1zrNIT9OM2CA32/VGgBrECQ3EAtE/ZFg7HYmHYiG4n5CBvcZut9ukTvtZvSEDzUhjtu10hwWAwRAoVC6Rx4dhkCgQNAvt8FZCORxkGAbhcVIKg3wIOwzwgaxx2bawzHiABPBsR1Ib9dFUAgXloVgUOvUgsF0ERgHYODCLwGVogAN0wM8CMwKYom0SDUObMxIPrAjWDwaxiGQzQsDYy9iDwXQ2MaGh6CYNgOHCARt2EUQQAkMQpB46wz0gRpUEcDJ6IAWheSEegMip0F%2BC5kERU9ImiZQICMUoUlIIxcmCUIfBcNw6Gcry/Hcdz8jCNIogyLISi0ZJBFkdIYkqILahCipsj88oEuqDy6kaXsWjaLg6wbJsW3I48AAVUAAdzsMru2AZBkB6bgAXnMEeggXBCBIb4h1SHpNB/d8ep%2BH56n60c4MaCAkG/V933IShZt/ex/0A7FuHYYBsR%2BC9wNYSDiGg2CCIQ2hkOEjCsJwvDyKIkiyII/AqMUWj6MPRjmNY9o0I4uRyI0/jiCQwSOjQghRPE76bykxgWDI%2BTBCU8RJCEXitIgHS9PcQzjNM8zLOs6FbLihynKispXLURLPNSXwfI8cmXLpjJqbqUL7MySo0vZ8KMqCYKYq5xnBeyVmwhyvt8s4QrG33UqGwq6riFq9aenqxrsQBH4gXazqiGIYa%2BoGua7ENsb1Am68ppm58TY/RbbeWlAAOQdbgFAvaDqO8jTvOqH0OfTD6Gu/DDzu0QHrDyiwrwV7yI%2B5AWNB9j6D%2B7jeMB4GMGTkSxIksC6Fh2TCgESEhBIlSUY09HMf0hsjJMsyCAsv5CeJmPSbUPy50pkxMoFzgL2Z9xu9A4eAn7pKuAvWKO851LhZ72eOYiqp%2BanweigXrwDCXvmahp%2BYJbyuSZeKg8OwbZwldVxYnk4SEdegBrcTGjr8H1w3SH6x2hsHKFzaWwnNOEAYILxcT3KQcS2IVhAlxJCPEI15grBGpCGEJUCLHlPLOS8k1bwPmmiAZoBBHAsQWl%2BX%2BbNMAfxIIIGGMl4a8EqvxRw%2BcuLn3lu0f%2BnAeiVUIAgHoisarqFVurHomttaHivBOW8SBiGkIIOQpa74cHUK6iFehcM5JMJYWwoqctMENn/iZPhBABHXzsLfe%2Bj95jtXVq/IBN5CHyLIZ%2BZRBRtxqP1nQwuDDtGkGYcwVhUMz4GMPMef%2BPxeH8MEVVYRasGpNRaguRxk4dztEgeJKEAJoQgmHKuWEq4VgrHmLwC%2BR4GzYLLtI2sICsQAnBBudaI0SlLjXOkn4YTL4nlwVbGWkIukVJ6TUtJtFDruBANwIAA%3D%3D) and [C++ mode](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxLrwAOqBYXW09hk4IeXmp0Vjb2Rk4uPIrKmKo%2BDATMxAR%2BxqacsSohtEkpBGF2js6uismp6QFZChWF1sWRpTwAlIqoBsTIHADkrHTAANToHQ7sg1QQ/aLDo%2BMAHi3iAAwAguIA7LJrg7uDaLS1g9NDIwZjmIMAItgA4gBK2NgA%2BgAqAPLP96tXg%2BIAzL9lgA6ZacDbcACs/0kAE5JJDOLDYdwYbDIdwIf8NpwAGwADmWkNhG3xuNh/wB21We32dCOJ1m53G3yub0%2BNweTz%2BgMGnGBgwA9Nc7o8Xh8vj8qSsaXtiJgCJ1aIN5gAqVns56csXStabK4ymWMs4XCaSKYDJmmxaGrYy2kHBmWk3jbVPTWsnlA0HgqFohFIlFojFYnEEokkskUiy62W7R0EY7OuaXDUSt3YL184EWIUirniz6s2O0%2BWK4jKtVpjmip6x/UynptVggHqQnqkUw9ZYd1CtnRyOSDBQdLqXKT/TgdgitnstNoAaxAknxwIx/1RkNxuLhuOh%2BP%2BQlb3A7XZ7pD7PQ7ChAy1IM%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%2B9O6JSv6aMB5BONhnj6HBgShJE4h0LE4vJOk2ToLoVGlLKARD3UsR5p0hwCaJ4zWzMiyrIIGzASpxznPp3J3N0RWzDZ/K5c5wLchZgXwsXjKkqn1Lsrnmod7oaXVflvf/CVvLZa3rX2hK5Ttcqs9e31hrnAOwZVleThJCt/r8Ft%2B2Y0JrOzthOf47t5qLUfPOUgS5IR3n4ieUgMkcTAlxMsAkB1JAQkhBsZYJIqqkUvNeW83toHPjfCtEAHQCBuE4oHbaIcsiYH/iQQQKNFLo14PVESbgG78UfnrHoE5OCDHqoQBAgw6qG2aq1dqnVuprigXOX21DOJ0IIAw4OpRJDeVYVFDhaNlLcN4fwiqusiGtgnBZcRBBJEGzfodS4ptBjm0tueB8KiqE0I0VoyapRDwsMGgYpunDjGkB4cwPhSMH4WPPJeMBYiJGDAcUbbgH8v4/w8UtbWSCZIrgthSTg/xcEIm4HCMEuJCHxNbCQ3RnimyLhAKgqEe4Dr/GxMsDcO4jw9H%2BHE5%2BV4yFzm1pIAZF5anDMaaQJiV03LcCAA%3D%3D%3D)

---

Regarding the bug, the first issue can be seen right from GCC's error message

> ```
>                ↓                                        ↓
> error: ‘(1.0e+0l / 1.74532925199432954743716805978693e-2l)’ is not a constant expression
> const constexpr long double RAD_TO_DEGREE = 1. / DEGREE_TO_RAD;
> ```

There's no `L` suffix in the source file, but somehow it appeared in the error output. And if I correct the code by adding the suffix it still fails with the same reason. I don't have a newer version of GCC for PowerPC so I can't verify this but the error occurs with [GCC 4.8.5 and 6.3.0, and even AT12.0 (which is based on GCC 8) on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5A1RsA1OlEAjBpnkAzCLIVKRq9QA8AlBwAMAQQ4B2PpfkP5aFoIJO5rzIYAOxeTuBFFTV5ABFsAHEAJWxsAH0AFQB5OKiLUPkOAGYMswA6M1prABYAViyuAE4uUtpKyuKKytLikqzrWgA2AA4zUsrrbs7KrOy7C0d3FzdnTx8/AKD9ELTQxJTw6NjMnPlaPPkAejDImPjk1PSx8wnHYkwCMRZ5QwAqVfW4zbPryxtQm43RZ6AyaLjaOSBEEhEyA2w3SazGYeAheXz%2BSFLUHfWKfVY7XIFIplJo1OoNJotNodHp9AZDEYAGV%2BtwcSKmc3RwOC6g%2BFxx2AJezyjKOJy25xSqxZk3uj2IzzefI2p1iLP%2BNykxkY0lKUlILGkZn1qGkAGF%2BPx5MIxBJMlwsrR9QQjVrtQBrEBcbp5FpZRqlTqdKqdcrdLI6qTFfWGqTG0imqT6wQgMykF1xrWkOCwGCIFCoAC23jwajIFAgaGLpcwxBA3m8yGAxW6pA0pdRxBTEGUrtIyjwLCYxAAntInaQq4XMCwCEkWAwx5nSFhC6xgGo%2B/h7sgCHgAG6YFPLryYZAiVHj/WD1EMPsMPDKYjDkdmjCSKQTgjEPCFq/a5g2BQS1eEYR8U0gbVUG8PcPGkABaVx0GyUJOF4fhaAnG1xEkWgAN1GM%2B0TAAFVAAHda2Is15GAZBkHkYo8h9Up5AgXBCBIe1HVIeQ32rMsuLw3iQJ4Z1XW1CAkCrEsy3IShpJrOsG2QTpijUYBOiyNN2wYTtu17ZcByHUcr0nItp1nedFy3TA1zYTdl23M890PY941Pc9L0/a9Z0wO9lwfJ8XzfLBTO/X9/0YddgPQ0DAogiAoJgvA4KkRCCGQnI0L4XhaGjIRRBwuh8KkPUDSI6RvHI2tVJCWj6M6PIsgKVj2KIPxuG43iixk2suK4YxhNi0T03E7MpJ6xS5MrSay3rRtVOAVsdL0ygDPjIyX1MqcZznBcl3jVd1wcw68B3Fyjz7DyLw/Ccbz8%2B9H2fUcQtu50fz/byAOi7L%2BDA5QEqS2CXAQpCUN%2B3KsMKiRisjMrY3jRMqoo4hVPkCwEloLgWrY/B2sEni%2BN6jqHSyQaLWGsTM2MD0QFKNN/Pyv9ikqPJ6nZjnOfK5dE2TVNRup7M80kkBRAIbwL2mhS5voTA8ZIOhSDI59vEi/z4YqqROtoeQyMIBB5FIlGqJouiGKY30qeNCSkDFiWCCl2bay9Ug5Y4ut6GVphVa%2BuHCJ56ROq4XX9fkZGarU9R6vkRrmvjDNrfG0WL3tx3%2BOdiM3faxWvZ9p0So1gOtdJkOCAN8PUeKdHMex%2BPxJKpmQBZtnOdb%2BpucR6Q%2Ba4AXrdpjo8jKUNVKydozH9YNIyyf3O6TXu3UjLgZ5NLv55p0hDy7FLDWKIA%3D%3D)

Indeed PowerPC uses [double-double arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Double-double_arithmetic) for [`long double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double) by default, but floating-point format is just an **internal implementation detail** that's *transparent to users*. It should **not** affect the compilation of correct code. Most embedded systems don't have floating-point support, and most current platforms don't have hardware for 128-bit `long double`. They all use software for those operations, yet floating-point code still compile fine on them. Regardless of the format, **valid code should compile and**

They do work if I [specify `-mabi=ieeelongdouble`](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5A1RsA1OlEAjBpnkAzCLIVKRq9QA8AlBwAMAQQ4B2PpfkP5aFoIJO5rzIYAOxeTuBFFTV5ABFsAHEAJWxsAH0AFQB5OKiLUPkOAGYMswA6M1prABYAViyuAE4uUtpKyuKKytLikqzrWgA2AA4zUsrrbs7KrOy7C0d3FzdnTx8/AKD9ELTQxJTw6NjMnPlaPPkAejDImPjk1PSx8wnHYkwCMRZ5QwAqVfW4zbPryxtQm43RZ6AyaLjaOSBEEhEyA2w3SazGYeAheXz%2BSFLUHfWKfVY7XIFIplJo1OoNJotNodHp9AZDEYAGV%2BtwcSKmc3RwOC6g%2BFxx2AJezyjKOJy25xSqxZk3uj2IzzefI2p1iLP%2BNykxkY0lKUlILGkZn1qGkAGF%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%2BF4WhiiwpgcJyPCCMhIiSNtcjKKkPUDRo6RvEY5ijJCDiuM6PIfTMQThKIPxuHEySNIrWS5q4YwFMypS0xUrN1M05jtLLRa9IM5AjOABsLKsygbLjOz70c0dx0nadZzjBclx8t68HXALd07ELj2fYdzyiq8bzvAcEqB5130/cLv3Syr%2BEA5QcryiCXGg2D4MQ5CkeqzCoOwvBcPwqKWp5NqyLoTrupjOME36pjiCM%2BQLASWguAKKb8BmuSJKkpbZodLI1otDblIzYwPRAUM8i4bprEDB1OjMMxvXrCMo1IT96jyeoDcNo2ernBMkxTLapc6rhqNN6RJeNaXSB3VsCsNYogA%3D%3D) though. Here you can also clearly see the difference between using and not using the `L` suffix, because without it the literal is a `double` and will be constructed at `double` precision before upcasting to `long double`, which means you'll lose all the digits beyond double precision. **Remember to always use the correct suffix in floating-point types if you don't use `double`**

```
.LC0:    # 1./0.0174532925199432954743716805978693
        .long   1074055773
        .long   3248897055
        .long   2108954270
        .long   2705146754
.LC1:    # 1.L/0.0174532925199432954743716805978693L
        .long   1074055773
        .long   3248897055
        .long   2108954270
        .long   2705146739
```

The constants are the same for [other platforms](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'long+double+f(long+double+x)%0A%7B%0A++++const+constexpr+long+double+DEGREE_TO_RAD+%3D+0.0174532925199432954743716805978693%3B%0A++++const+constexpr+long+double+RAD_TO_DEGREE+%3D+1.+/+DEGREE_TO_RAD%3B%0A++++return+x*RAD_TO_DEGREE%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Along+double+f2(long+double+x)%0A%7B%0A++++const+constexpr+long+double+DEGREE_TO_RAD+%3D+0.0174532925199432954743716805978693L%3B%0A++++const+constexpr+long+double+RAD_TO_DEGREE+%3D+1.L+/+DEGREE_TO_RAD%3B%0A++++return+x*RAD_TO_DEGREE%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:33.7122376399665,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:mips564,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O2+-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'MIPS64+gcc+5.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0'),(h:compiler,i:(compiler:arm64g820,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O2+-std%3Dc%2B%2B14',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0'),(h:compiler,i:(compiler:riscv820,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O2+-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'RISC-V+gcc+8.2.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:66.28776236003348,l:'4',m:99.99999999999999,n:'0',o:'',s:2,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) that use [IEEE-754 quadruple-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format)